# apache redirect from one domain to another domain but the subdomain is redirected?

Tags: apache, redirect

below is my apache 2.4 config file.Today i have move the old domain www.58trust.me to the new domain www.58xintuo.com. Now the problem is,when i visit vc.58xintuo.com, it is redirect to www.58xintuo.com.How can i fix it?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.58trust.me
    #ServerAlias www.58trust.me
    RedirectPermanent / http://www.58xintuo.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin plsytj@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/bbs
    ServerName 58xintuo.com
    ServerAlias www.58xintuo.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Where is vc.58xintuo.com supposed to go to?  Do you have a config for that subdomain? I don't see it anywhere in your config.